# Error with "TYPE_FORWARD_ONLY" in sqlite

Tags: sql, jdbc, resultset

I am working with SQLite and JDBC and getting this error about the result_set being TYPE_FORWARD_ONLY.

```
    PreparedStatement get_mileage = conn.prepareStatement("SELECT * FROM workout_log");
    ResultSet mileage_count = get_mileage.executeQuery();

    mileage_count.absolute(week_start);

    for (int i=week_start;i<=week_finish;i++){
        total_mileage+=mileage_count.getInt(1);
        mileage_count.next();
    }
```

The error is on the call to `absolute()` even though I know it is not moving backwards at all.  I have tried adding flags to `prepareStatement` but it says my version of SQLite does not support `ResultSet` that is not FORWARD_ONLY.

My question is why is this occuring, even though I am not moving backward?

Comment: Just a note, please follow normal Java naming conventions (ie CamelCasing); it increases the readability for Java programmers

Answer (score 5):

A `TYPE_FORWARD_ONLY ResultSet` only supports `next()` for navigation, and not methods like `first()`, `last()`, `absolute(int)`, `relative(int)`. The JDBC specification explicitly defines those to throw a `SQLException` if called on a `TYPE_FORWARD_ONLY`:

Javadoc of [`ResultSet.absolute(int)`](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/sql/ResultSet.html#absolute%28int%29):

> **Throws:**
>       `SQLException` - if a database access error occurs; this method is called on a closed result set or the result set type is `TYPE_FORWARD_ONLY`

Using those methods does not make a lot of sense with a `TYPE_FORWARD_ONLY`: that type of result set is not intended for 'random access' of the rows, like the scrollable result sets are.

For example with a `TYPE_FORWARD_ONLY`:

- Calling `first()` would only work when you are positioned before the first row (and on the first row itself), so why not just use `next()`
- Calling `absolute(int)` would only work if you pass a row higher than the current row, and you could never go back to earlier rows
- Calling `relative(int)` would only work if you pass a positive value and you can never go back to earlier rows
- Calling `last()` would make you skip the rest of the result set and you can never go back to earlier rows

Admittedly: it might have its uses, but it would needlessly complicate the driver with the additional constraints of being `TYPE_FORWARD_ONLY`.

If you want random access, you need to declare that you want random access by specifying one of the scrollability types `TYPE_SCROLL_INSENSITIVE` or `TYPE_SCROLL_SENSITIVE`. If your driver doesn't support these types, then you may need to simulate it with for example `CachedRowSet` (specifically `com.sun.rowset.CachedRowSetImpl`), or by first loading the entire ResultSet (eg into a `List<? extends List<Object>>`).