# CachedRowSet and SQLite JDBC driver

Tags: java, sqlite, jdbc, driver, rowset

I'm trying to use CachedRowSet with SQLite and Xerial driver https://bitbucket.org/xerial/sqlite-jdbc .

If I call execute() method like that:

```
  Connection connection = DriverManager.getConnection("jdbc:sqlite:sample.db");
  CachedRowSet crs = new CachedRowSetImpl();
  crs.setCommand("select * from person");
  crs.execute(connection);
```

I'm getting the SQLException "not implemented by SQLite JDBC driver":

```
    at com.sun.rowset.internal.CachedRowSetReader.readData(Unknown Source)
    at com.sun.rowset.CachedRowSetImpl.execute(Unknown Source)
    at com.sun.rowset.CachedRowSetImpl.execute(Unknown Source)
    at com.oracle.tutorial.jdbc.CachedRowSetSample.testPaging(CachedRowSetSample.java:100)
    at com.oracle.tutorial.jdbc.CachedRowSetSample.main(CachedRowSetSample.java:273)
```

on the other hand ResultSet and populate() insteed of excecute() works ok:

```
  Connection connection = DriverManager.getConnection("jdbc:sqlite:sample.db");
  statement = connection.createStatement();
  ResultSet rs = statement.executeQuery("select * from person");
  CachedRowSet crs = new CachedRowSetImpl();
  crs.populate(rs);
```

Does anybody know whats wrong with execute()?

Comment: Please post the full exception stacktrace. Also: why do you want to use `CachedRowSet`, in my opinion it is rather buggy and it is rarely useful.

Comment: the above exception is from oracle example , I've reduced the coding and here the full exception but in my opinion has no new information: 
`Exception in thread "main" java.sql.SQLException: not implemented by SQLite JDBC driver at com.sun.rowset.internal.CachedRowSetReader.readData(Unknown Source) at com.sun.rowset.CachedRowSetImpl.execute(Unknown Source) at First.rowSet1(First.java:33) at First.main(First.java:79)`

Comment: I would have expected an exception cause that includes which method is called in the SQLite driver that actually throws that "not implemented by SQLite JDBC driver", but looking at the actual code in `CachedRowSetReader` it throws a new exception with the message of the initial exception without setting the exception cause... As I said: in my opinion it is rather buggy and it is rarely useful.

Comment: thanx a lot for your answer, which nativ implementation of disconnected RowSet do you recommend?

Comment: I think this problem could be specific for SQLite, the  tutorial of oracle works ok with MySql. Perhaps some options are important by establishing the connection to SQLite?

Answer (score 0):

Unfortunately there's a handful of JDBC functions you'll have to implement workarounds for when using SQLite. This happens to be one of them. Probably the best alternate solution is to put the entire result set into a List<> and work with that:

```
// Variables. 
final int TIMEOUT_DEFAULT=30;
String query = "select * from person";
ResultSet rs;
Statement statement;
List<String[]> people;

...

// Create query and execute. (Connection established, database open.)
try {                
    statement = connection.createStatement();
    statement.setQueryTimeout(TIMEOUT_DEFAULT);
    connection.setAutoCommit(true);
    rs = statement.executeQuery(query);  
} catch (SQLException e) {
    // If error, close connection & ignore close errors.
    try { connection.close(); } 
        catch (SQLException e2) { /* Ignore */ }
    // Throw new error.
    throw new SQLException("Query failed",e);
}

// Retrieve results.
try {
    people = new ArrayList<>();
    while (rs.next()) {
        people.add(new String[]{
            rs.getString(1), rs.getString(2), rs.getString(3)
        });
    }
} catch (SQLException e) {
    // If error, close connection & ignore close errors.
    try { connection.close(); } 
        catch (SQLException e2) { /* Ignore */ }
    // Throw new error.
    throw new SQLException("Error retrieving data",e);
}

// Close connection, ignore error.
try { 
    connection.close(); 
} catch (SQLException e) { /* Ignore */ }

// Print output.
for (String[] p : people) {
    System.out.println(Arrays.deepToString(p));
}
```

An answer in [this post](https://stackoverflow.com/a/16494765/7326283) contains a comment about simulating a function if it's not supported by your driver.